# Moq - Setup Method with Expression of anonymous type

Tags: c#, generics, moq

I have a function with this signature -

```
TSelect Get<TSelect>(int id, Expression<Func<T, TSelect>> select);
```

`T` is declared on the class level. It's meant to allow developers to pass in the shape they wish the object to be returned as, like `.Select` in Linq.

So it's usage looks like

```
_query.Get(123, x => new { x.Id, x.Name })
```

I cannot figure out how to set this up in Moq. I've seen a lot of answers about using `It.IsAnyType`, but that doesn't seem to work in an expression. And Moq doesn't match anonymous types to objects by design, so `Expression<Func<MyType, object>>` doesn't work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what are you exactly trying to mock? Imagine the mocking was working, could you plz add a pseudocode to make your question more clear?
I am not sure if you are trying to make a mock expression, mock the `Get` function for a given type `T`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to mock for a `select` function that returns an instance of an anonymous type, you could achieve this by a helper function:

```csharp
public class MyUnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        var query = CreateMockQuery(
            new Person { Name = "Bob" },
            new { Id = default(int), Name = default(string) } // Declares the anonymous type
        );

        var result = query.Get(5, p => new { Id = 5, p.Name });
        Assert.Equal("Bob", result.Name);
    }

    private IQuery<T> CreateMockQuery<T, TSelect>(
        T source,
        TSelect _ /* captures the anonymous type*/)
    {
        var mockQuery = new Mock<IQuery<T>>();
        mockQuery
            .Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<T, TSelect>>>()))
            .Returns(
                (int id, Expression<Func<T, TSelect>> select)
                    => select.Compile()(source));
        return mockQuery.Object;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IQuery<T>
{
    TSelect Get<TSelect>(int id, Expression<Func<T, TSelect>> select);
}
```

To avoid passing an anonymous type as a generic type argument, we can pass it as the input to `CreateMockQuery` so the compiler could automatically detect the type.